# How to display SurfaceTextures on a TextureView in android

Tags: android, textureview, android-textureview

I am trying to view `SurfaceTextures` in  `TextureView` ,  i am getting `SurfaceTextures` from a callback

```
            @Override
            public void onNewTexture(SurfaceTexture texture) {
                Log.d(TAG, "On New Texture");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(texture);
                    }
                });
                 texture.detachFromGLContext();
          });
```

above code snippet displays only First texture and after that `textureView` freezes (like image below)

[image]

some of the logs while application is freezed state are attached [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kjzKrNrKMRKZ4W1hY45gPLAIg5p3xOjkPePlSqFT9sY/edit?usp=sharing)

i wanted to know is it the right way to view `SurfaceTexture` in android if yes , what is the problem with above code ,

i am quiet new to this area of android and spent day together , any help or clue related this problem will be big help for me